# What is a RAM state in the gym's breakout-ram environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, implementation, gym

I have encountered the gym environment and decided to create AI that plays breakout. Here is the link: https://gym.openai.com/envs/Breakout-ram-v0/.

The documentation says that the state is represented as a RAM state, but what is the RAM in this context? Is it the random access memory? What does the RAM state represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the state of the memory; this would mainly involve variables, since the code would be in ROM. Since it is only 128 bytes in size, the screen memory would also not be included in this.

The idea is that all information relevant to the game is captured in these 128 bytes; they represent the *state* of the game world at any given time. Movements of the ball, the game controller position, etc are all encoded there.

For machine learning it is not actually relevant *which* bytes are representing which value, as any optimisation of outcomes will treat all these 128 bytes as parameters describing the state. A machine learning system will pick up the optimal configuration through the learning process, eg that the 'racket' position should always near the ball x-coordinate. That will just be a correlation of two bytes, no matter which ones they actually are.

Comment: and what does this information represents?what state of memory i don't understand this term at all, please help me

Comment: if you were given array of 128 numbers and told to build neural network, isn't it important what these 128 numbers represents?it's very abstract to me.

Comment: @datonefaridze see update